# Short sound when toggling a light indicator

Tags: components

What is that “click” sound we hear when a light indicator turns on or off on some very simple devices, like the lights that tell us when some flatirons or ovens are heating up?

I can’t open the circuitry of my oven just to find out what controls the light. What electric or electronic device which makes a little “click” when toggling its output could be used to control a light? And why would this device be better than a LED/transistor pair? (I’m speaking of recent devices, built in this decade, not my great grandmother’s charcoal flatiron!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click is likely a bimetalic strip that turns on or off the oven heater. The light is also attached to the same heater circuit so gets switched on or off. Devices in this decade still have them as they are the cheapest way to control high wattage heaters. The "led" is likely only a neon bulb, or if indeed a led, it is often connected with just a current limiting resistor.

Comment: Not only cheap; they are also damn reliable!

Comment: It could be a thermal sensor driven relay such as my surface stove

Comment: I want to reinforce the point made by @MarcusMüller. They are extremely reliable, especially when used in high temperature applications. Probably nowadays some form of integrated electronic switch could compete on the "cheapness" side, but definitely not on reliability! BTW I've seen mechanical power switch fail in my life, I've never seen one of those bimetallic switches fail unless heavily brutalized (e.g. hard fall on the floor, hit by a big foot, etc.)

Comment: @LorenzoDonati thinking about this, I actually had failures of such. Actually, two name-brand water cookers stopped switching off. But that was due to inadequate mounting of the switch (which was at the point just a piece of bimetal embedded in the plastic case itself).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well, that is more a product design fail than a component fail in itself, IMO. I cannot quote hard data, but I've seen several bimetallic switch in household thermostats that worked for decades flawlessly switching ~2kW loads. I personally own a ~40yrs old portable electric heater (~2.5kW) mounting such a thermostat. Never a glitch!

Comment: definitely! I just wanted to relax my statement a bit: It's not that I've *never* seen a bimetal strip system fail. I did. But they're still darn reliable